# How to create a BubbleMap in with AnyChart for Android in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, charts, anychart

### INFO

I'm trying to create a BubbleMap in Android Studio.
But I have no clue how to. 
I found an [example](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/BubbleMapActivity.java), but I don't fully understand it at the moment.
My main problem is how to set the geoData (line 46) and then draw the GeoMap.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At lines 105 and 106, the file with the map of Australia and proj4.js is loaded from the assets folder. You should [create an assets folder](http://code2care.org/2015/create-assets-folder-in-android-studio/) in your project and place these files there. At line 46 the map file is applied to the chart. Maps provided by AnyChart you can download from [our CDN page](https://www.anychart.com/download/cdn/?v=8.7.1), open the page, scroll down a bit to the "Geo Data" section. You need only `JavaScript (Geo)` format.
The proj4.js you can download by [the link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js).